Custom Search Pattern using Search & Filter pro and elementor
You can go to https://chefnetwork.shopifyappsforyou.com/search/ and you can check the scenario 1 sorting is applied.
I am using following of the plugins:

Elementor Pro
CPTUI and ACF
Dynamic.ooo
Search & Filter Pro
Relevanssi Premium

Pre knowledge:
I have a custom post type Talents with slug='talent' and it has different taxonomies the reuired one is Cuisines with slug='cuisine'. There is custom radio field attached to the 'talent' post type called 'talent_fee' with numerical values in it.
There are 4 terms in 'talent_fee' (10000, 20000, 50000 and 100000) and this is for acting as fee range.
Problem statement:
I want to make the search results in such a way that there should be 3 or 2 groups of search result, showing one after other are following:
1. If searched term matches with the title of 'talent', talent_fee **descending **and in each range **names **should be ascending. e.g (5 results in 50000 and 10 in 100000, results with 10000 shows before and the 10 results should be in order name ascending, same for 50000 as its 11-16th result name ascending in 50000 talent_fee).
2. If searched term matches with the term of 'cuisine', fee_range and name sort will be applied.
3. If searched term matches within the content, fee_range and name sort will be applied.
Note. In most of the results at least 2 groups (1,2 or 2,3) exists, as the search is a search form created using search & filter pro.
Search Page:
Search page is created with elementor the Dynamic Posts widget (extension in Dynamic.ooo) is used to show the result, query is selected search & filter and the form is selected.
Current Scenario:

There can default sort applied using search & filter,
a. I am using the talent_fee descending as main sort
b. And Name Ascending as secondary sort.
problem: It gets the results from all 3 mentioned groups above and apply sort on that list of total talents.

I have used the relevance plugin to set the weight of the elements like title, content, talent_fee and cuisine, 10, 1, 5, 8 respectively.
problem: It shows the results in a way that macthed titles comes first then the content but its not working with cuisine and the sorting do not work as we can use the order from either one of (wordpress, search & pro or relevanssi).


Appeal:
Kindly help me through it as I've already tried to apply too many query generated by ChatGPT.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
